# User Agent Stylesheet Overriding Own Styles

Tags: css

The outer div in the below html snippet is supposed to have css of `{cursor: pointer}` applied to it but it is being overridden by `user agent stylesheet`, as I can see when I look up the computed styles in the chrome developer tools.

```
<div class="select clickable">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: _regions,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'geonameId',
            value: selectedCity,
            optionsCaption: 'REGION'
            "><option value="">REGION</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Here is my relevant css:

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

I guess I need to use a better selector for the css rule. What is a selector that will override user agent stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the selector to the select element:

```css
.clickable select {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="select clickable">
    <span class="arr"></span>
    <select data-bind="options: _regions,optionsText: 'name',optionsValue: 'geonameId',value: selectedCity,optionsCaption: 'REGION'">
        <option value="">REGION</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers. I'm looking at some css selector cheat sheets and they do not say what [.class element] is actually selecting. What will this select? All my divs and buttons of class clickable still seem to be selected with this selector.

Comment: It's selecting the `<select>` element. The div with class `.clickable` extends the width of the viewport, while the `<select>` element covers the entire region of the dropdown. If this is your preferred answer, please vote for it.